# Assigning IPv6 address to user

Tags: networking, ipv6

Is it possible to assign a different static IPv6 address to each user on the system?

Comment: It seems that you may have [an XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/1081494). Generally each network interface gets an IP, not each user. It might be do-able if you had a NIC with multiple ports or something, but what is your goal? What are you trying to accomplish by giving each user a separate IP address?

Comment: The idea is to separate each account's networking. For example, account1 is running some docker containers for a certain task, and would like to keep it separated from account2 that runs different processes. Also, account1 may connect and browse the internet under its own ipv6 address, which account2 would have its own address.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69876563/docker-assigning-ipv6-address-in-docker-run

Comment: In Linux you can separate processes and networking in namespaces. Docker does this in simple ways, you can start dockers, but assigning IPv6 addresses by user without docker will be super hard. You're best of using the --ip6 flag to give each docker container its own IP address

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I found exactly what I needed, in a solution that uses `iptables` https://serverfault.com/questions/236721/bind-process-or-user-to-specific-ip-linux

So for example in my case, I would use `ip6tables` like this:

```
ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m owner --uid-owner user1 -j SNAT --to-source 2001:db8:dead:bee1::
ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m owner --uid-owner user2 -j SNAT --to-source 2001:db8:dead:bee2::
```

Then verify that user1 is indeed using the assigned IPv6 address (IPv4 or IPv6 can be forced by passing the appropiate flag to the client, e.g curl -4 or curl -6):

```
su user1
curl -6 ifconfig.co
```